# SharePoint online powershell script timezone issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I developed a script to add calendar events for our SharePoint on-premise for ET timezone, but when I run the same script for SharePoint online, I see a difference in the timezone though my regional settings are set to ET timezone.

Is there a way to hard code the timezone entry for SharePoint online?

Comment: Did you try the code below ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the TimeZone using SharePoint Online CSOM like this:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Config parameters for SharePoint Online Site URL and Timezone description
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"
$TimezoneName ="(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Set up the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $credentials

#Get all available time zones
$Timezones = $Ctx.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones
$Ctx.Load($Timezones)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Filter the Time zone to update
$NewTimezone = $Timezones | Where {$_.Description -eq $TimezoneName}

#sharepoint online powershell set time zone
$Ctx.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $NewTimezone
$Ctx.Web.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

[image]

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Change Time Zone using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/sharepoint-online-change-time-zone-using-powershell.html)